# Excel - copy file from one folder to another if cell is clicked on

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy my file from one folder to another folder when a user clicks on a cell in excel.

I keep getting an error saying file not found error, and I don't know why.

my folder names have spaces in so I don't know if this might be the cause of the problem, I have tried removing the spaces in the folder path but same error occurs. can someone please show me what to do thanks in advance

```
      If Target.Column = Range("C1").Column Then
  If Target.Row > 9 Then
    'Declare Variables
 Dim FSO
 Dim sFile As String
 Dim sSFolder As String
 Dim sDFolder As String

'This is Your File Name which you want to Copy
 sFile = "Supplier Audit.xls"

'Change to match the source folder path
 sSFolder = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets"

'Change to match the destination folder path
 sDFolder = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\AX ATTACHMENTS\TEST"

'Create Object
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
 If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
 MsgBox "Specified File Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"

'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
 ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
 FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
 MsgBox "Specified File Copied Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
 Else
 MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"


  End If
  End If
  End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a backslash at the end of `sSFolder`. Thats why `sDFolder & sFile` result is

```
\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assetsSupplier Audit.xls.
```

Put a backslash at the end of `sDFolder` too.

Comment: when I try and add a backslash to sSfolder I get a syntax error

Comment: `sSFolder = "\\UKSH000-FILE06\purchasing\New Supplier Set-Ups\assets\" ` is executed well on my side. What version of Excel do you use? Try to do it in this way: `sDFolder & "\" & sFile` or use a double backslash.

Comment: I used Excel 2007 to run it. I'll try to test it in Excel 2010 as soon as I find it somewhere. If someone can check what is the problem with backslash ended strings please write here.

Comment: Checked in Excel 2013. Backslash works. The only difference with your code is a backslash at the end of sSFolder and sDFolder before ending quotes. Also the folders were on a local machine. If you still have errors provide more info about them.